# Issue with "Add the 'Save to Drive' button", throwing 404 requested URL not found on server

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, actions-on-google, google-api-js-client

We have integrated Add the "Save to Drive" button in our code, It works perfectly for most of the cases.

But in one case it is throwing error 404, requested URL not found on server, Can you help with what might be the cause of this
[Screenshot of error coming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXAJE.png)

We have tried incognito node and without extension same thing is happening there as well. And it is a enterprise gmail account, where we are try to save to drive

Comment: check your requested URL correct path or not if route path is wrong from server throws 404 error.

Comment: The url is being opened by google only, we can't update or access the url. We are using the approach mentioned in https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/savetodrive